# Is it true more CPU core is better for deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu, hardware

I just started to learn the deep learning in my free time. I was hoping to buy a laptop where I want to implement some small(alexnet) to medium(GoogleNet) networks maybe something bigger. I searched for the GPU. Everyone is suggesting minimum RTX 2060. However, it's vague about the CPU. I heard people saying that it's better to have more number of core in CPU. All I understand CPU only do the data pre-processing. What I want to know is it feasible to have a 4 core CPU(e.g. i5 9300H) with RTX 2060 having a tight budget? Will this configuration serve my purpose?

Another things is new 10th Gen Intel Core i7-10750H processor with up to 5.0 GHz3 have a 6 cores. While AMD Ryzen 7 4800HS have 8 cores. Which will be best for deep learning. Is the number of cores really matters?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to go with a good GPU than CPU. Most of the time you will train your model on a GPU which gives you around 100x speed boost compared to CPU. So i guess your first config is good enough for normal DL task.